# Edit distance vs. canonical adjacency matrix distance

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs, isomorphism-testing, graph-distance, nauty

Let $G$ and $G'$ be two simple random graphs on the same set of nodes. Let $d_{edit}$ be the edit distance between $G$ and $G'$. Let $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{A'}$ be the adjacency matrices of the graphs $G$ and $G'$ that result from the canonical labeling algorithm Nauty. Moreover, let $d_{matrix} = \frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{A'}\|$.

What is the difference (in expectation) between the two distances?
That is, what can we say about $\mathbb{E}[d_{matrix}-d_{edit}]$?

Clearly, $d_{matrix} \geq d_{edit}$. Also, if transforming $G$ to $G'$ doesn't change the canonical ordering of $G$'s nodes, then we have $d_{matrix}=d_{edit}$ (the special case, of course, being that $G$ and $G'$ are isomorphic).

Comment: To clarify: The matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{A'}$ are the ones that result from a canonical labeling of the graphs. It's therefore not quite correct to say "lexicographically maximal". It's best to consider the ordering of the nodes to result from a coloring of the Weisfeiler-Lehman algorithm where ties are broken based on a lexicographic order. (I.e., what Nauty does.)